# How do we link a Facebook page and a separate App?

Tags: facebook

I made an application for using Facebook's likes/comments.
This is the [app](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=199487673409178).

However, I made a separate [fan page](http://facebook.com/thinkiota).

How do I link the two such that the App's Profile Page points to the one that I have made?
I can't afford to  make a new page since I have already gathered 250+ likes, and it was hard.

Comment: You can't. Making an app just to collect likes was the incorrect method if you want the likes to appear on your fan page.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook changes their user interface once in a while, and it can be difficult how to add an app as a tab to a Facebook page.

Here is how you do it:

1. The app must be a tab app. When you create the app, you get a chance to specify a Page tab URL and a Secure Page Tab URL. If the app is set up as a "App on Facebook", it will not work. Make sure your app is set up as a "Page Tab"
2. After you create the Tab app, click on "View App Profile Page" in the left column.
3. Click "Add to My Page"
4. Select the page to which you want to add this tab and click the close button

There is a step by step tutorial on how to do this here:

http://how-to-create-facebook-app.koliber.com

Answer (score 0):

You can link the app to the page by clicking the "link to my page" link at the lower left of the app screen. A box pops up that lists all the pages you are an administrator of. Just select the one you are targeting.

The app including its info content will then appear as an extra tab/menu item on your page. That way, the visitors of your page have direct access to your app.